# ¿Como validar en PHP la salida de cierta cantidad si no hay sufuciente en stock?

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación el cual tengo un modulo de registro de productos, en la base de datos tengo ambas tablas una de salida y otro de inventario, hasta el momento me están funcionando bien, pero quiero validar un detalle que cuando se de salida de 10 productos más y en stock solo hay 7 me notifique que no hay suficiente productos.

Lo que quiero saber si se puede agregar un select en php que tengo ya y verificar la cantidad del registro de salida y llamar la tabla del inventario del campo stock aplicando un operador lógico.

**registro de salida php**

```
<?php

   include('conexion.php');

   $codigospa = $_POST["codigo_spa"];
   $descriProdu = $_POST["descripcion_pro"];
   $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
   $unidadMedi = $_POST["unidadMedida"];
   $fechaSalida = $_POST["fechaSalida"];

   $query = "INSERT INTO t_salida_produc_albergue(codigo_spa,descripcion_pro,cantidad,
   unidadMedida,fechaSalida)
   VALUES('$codigospa','$descriProdu','$cantidad','$unidadMedi','$fechaSalida')";

  $result = $mysql->query($query);

  if ($result) {
  echo "1";

  } else {
  echo "2";
 }
 $mysql->close();

?>
```

**tabla de inventario**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hace falta un poco mas de detalles.Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una consulta de stock previa a la inserción y comparas el valor del stock contra la cantidad que te llega por `$_POST`.

```
$stock = "SELECT stock FROM inventario WHERE codigo_ia = $codigospa";
if($cantidad > $stock) {
    #muestras la alerta
} else {
    #haces el insert
}
```

Comment: Voy a verificar eso que me comentas DjCrazy

Comment: Ya lo verifique, solo que tengo una duda en en el `else` tengo que colocar el `if ($result)` ya que esa condición me inserta los datos

Comment: Claro que si, dentro de cada condicional agregas el código necesario para que funcione como esperas, el ejemplo es solo para darte una idea de cómo puedes manejar tu caso ya que desconozco cómo manejas las alertas y otros detalles. El orden correcto sería, incluir la conexión, recibir los datos que te llegan del formulario a través de `$_POST`, hacer la consulta de stock, comparar cantidad contra stock, en el `if` muestras la alerta, en el `else` va el contenido de  **$query**, **$result** y el condicional  `if ($result) {...}` y al final, fuera del primer condicional, `$mysql->close();`

Comment: Algo importante a tener en cuenta, la extensión `mysql` está obsoleta y fue retirada en `php` 7, en su lugar deberías usar `mysqli` o `PDO`. [Mas info aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-close.php)